Spivak Exercise, Prove Vandermonde's Identity $\sum_{k=0}^{l}\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{l-k}=\binom{n+m}{l}$
Prove that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{l}\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{l-k}=\binom{n+m}{l}$$

Hint: Apply the binomial theorem to $(1+x)^n(1+x)^m$

Proof:
Following Spivak's advice, we have
$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k=(1+x)^n$ and $\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{m}{j}x^j=(1+x)^m$
Since $(1+x)^n(1+x)^m=(1+x)^{n+m}$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k\cdot \sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{m}{j}x^j=\sum_{(j+k)=0}^{n+m}\binom{n+m}{j+k}x^{j+k}$$
Which is the sum of all numbers in the form $\left\langle \binom{n}{k}x^k \cdot\binom{m}{j}x^j \right\rangle$ At this point we should realize that $\binom{n+m}{l}$ represents the coefficient for $x^l$. So we only care about terms of the l'th order so we make the restriction that $j+k=l$. In other words we want the sum of all the numbers in the form$\left\langle \binom{n}{k}x^k \cdot\binom{m}{l-k}x^{l-k} \right\rangle$ .
$$(\sum_{k=0}^{l}\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{l-k})x^l=\binom{n+m}{l}x^l$$
Q.E.D

Yeah, the problem is $\sum_{j+k=0}^l.$ if that means anything, it means a sum over all pairs $(j,k)$ such that $0\leq j+k\leq 1,$ which gives too many terms.

This isn't what you asked, but a much more illuminating way to establish the fact is a combinatorial proof. Suppose there's a club with $n$ male members and $m$ female members (please excuse my gender binarism here). In how many ways can we form an $l$-person committee? Approach 1 is to select all $l$ from the membership at large, which you can do in ${n+m}\choose l$ ways. Approach 2 is to decide how many of the $l$ members will be male, call that number $k$. Then sum over all possible values of $k$. Done!

If you fixed the summation formula for $(1+x)^{m+n}$ to use the correct formula, then the proof works.

No, you should write
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk x^k \cdot \sum_{j=0}^m \binom mj x^j = \sum_{s=0}^{m+n} \binom{m+n}s x^s.$$
Now compare the coefficients of $x^l$ on both sides. So you will need $j+k=l$, and then your reasoning can be written down succinctly.

You should say what is wrong. And maybe mention/link to the term "Cauchy product."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

I'm sorry, I've been thinking about it and I still don't understand why the expression $\sum_{j+k=0}^{n+m}\binom{n+m}{j+k}x^{j+k}$ is incorrect. Could you please explain it to me? Thank you!

It’s not formally incorrect, but it is confusing. When you write a single summation, there should be a single variable that starts somewhere and increments by $1$ at each step.  Let’s give that single variable its own name. $j$ and $k$ have a context on the left-hand side and then we compare the coefficients of $x^l$.
